# Why can't I push a const pointer to std::vector?

Tags: c++11, vector, push-back

Consider the piece of code:

```
class T;

void constructVector(const T* item)
{
   std::vector<T*> v;
   v.push_back(item);
}
```

I get an error with MSVC 2010 compiler:

> error: C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from 'const T *' to 'T *&&' with [
>       _Ty=T * ] Conversion loses qualifiers

I can see this particular conversion is illegal, but I don't believe my code is semantically wrong. I also believe there's `push_back(const T&)` variant, why isn't that matched to my call?

Comment: You have a vector of non const items and you're pushing a const item. It's telling you they're not the same thing.

Comment: @Jay: Oh, I see what you mean! Stupid question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because that's a vector of non-const pointers.  It won't convert a const pointer to a non-const pointer.  That would defeat the purpose of const.

I believe that the push_back(const T&) is not what you're looking for, because that makes the T object *itself* const, it does not change the *type* of T from (*) to (const *).

You could make the vector a vector of const pointers :

```
void constructVector(const T* item)
{
    std::vector<const T*> v;
    v.push_back(item);
 }
```

Or you could change your function to take a non-const pointer :

```
 void constructVector(T* item)
 {
    std::vector<T*> v;
    v.push_back(item);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop `const`

void constructVector( <s>const</s> T* item);

or

Use:

```
void constructVector(const T* item)
{
   std::vector<const T*> v;
   v.push_back(item);
}
```

Comment: It's apparent that `const` is the stopper here, I just couldn't understand why until Jay's comment.